# I instantly get disconnected from SSH (Locked out of box-almost)

Tags: ssh

**I cannot login to my Debian Wheezy server via SSH.**

I changed Ciphers and KeyExchange options in ssh_config and sshd_config. The weird thing is that I made the same changes on two other identical machines and didn't run into any problems.

**Luckily I have VNC access to I can get into the machine to make any changes.**

I have now reverted my ssh configs back to normal but the problem persists:

```
debug1: Connecting to myserv.com [server_ip] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/antd/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/antd/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/antd/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/antd/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/antd/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/antd/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/antd/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/antd/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/antd/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [myserv.com]:443
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[myserv.com]:443" from file "/Users/antd/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
disconnected
```

And after restarting SSH service:

```
sh-4.2$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
[....] Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshdCould not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

SSH is not even asking for my password either...

I would highly appreciate it if someone can help me get SSH back!!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by issuing this command:

sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

For some reason everything works now.